# Why Adaptive card is always showing error something went wrong please try again on submit?

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

Adaptive Card action button is not responding properly in teams application., when we click button
always showing **something went wrong please try again**
please refer below image for error details.

[image: Adaptive card something went wrong please try again]

```
actions: [
      {
        type: "Action.Submit",
        title: `${translation.BotSection.Login}`,
        data: {
          msteams: {
            type: "task/fetch",
          },
          login: "botlogin",
        },
      },
    ],
```

Comment: I found an issue related to account is logged in two different places., please validate and let me know thanks.

Comment: Please share your Adaptive card JSON.

Comment: Might be that adaptive card action is not properly handled by the bot

Comment: @sivasubramanian -  Kindly validate your Card JSON and check it once.

Comment: Tried myself it is working fine. Can you share how are you handling the request. See how I  did - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk5zL.png. For more details you can follow this sample -  [link](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/54.teams-task-module)

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft  :  I am facing the same the exact same issue . [Here is my adaptive card JSON ](https://filebin.net/dgf94wcp4n99hpg3#) . It seems to be a channel specific issue , same adaptive card works fine for webchat.  Any help or pointers would be appreciated .